# Calculating Sales Tax Task Javascript

Tags: javascript, task

I'm asked to the following tasks but am having difficulty returning values.
Here's the code:

```
function calculateTaxes(price, quantity) {
    var salesTax = .10;
    var totalPrice;
    return totalPrice;
}

// Test Your Code Here
calculateTaxes(1,10);
```

- calculateTaxes(1,10) should return a number
- calculateTaxes(2,5) should return a value of 11
- calculateTaxes(5,6) should return a value of 33
- calculateTaxes(10,3) should return a value of 33
- calculateTaxes(15,12) should return a value of 198
- calculateTaxes(25,2) should return a value of 55

Comment: But what is the logic to calculate the sales tax?

Comment: Maybe it's the task to find out

Comment: Well, homework questions not allowed on SO.

Comment: @DotNetDev
Your right, it's the task to find out.  I've tried a few approaches but i'm not getting the desired result.  I"ll keep playing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite straightforward. `price*quantity` gives you the total price without tax, and multiplying that with `1 + salesTax` gives you the price after tax.

```js
function calculateTaxes(price, quantity) {
    var salesTax = .10;
    var totalPrice = (price * quantity) * (1 + salesTax);
    return totalPrice;
}

console.log(calculateTaxes(1,10));
console.log(calculateTaxes(25,2));
```

Don't be surprised if you see `55.00000001` instead of `55` though. Do read: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @Deepak Kamat, or you can mind your own business instead of trolling. If your not helping don't say anything. Anyone can be a critic.

Comment: @Nisarg Shaw
Worked awesome.  Thank u.

Comment: @PreYVin I don't mean to be rude but your question doesn't follow community guidelines. This isn't a homework sharing Q&A site to be brutally honest.

Comment: Yeah well this is a community of developers that are responsible for the learning process.  If you can't understand that or incapable of helping, don't bother. If you want to be cyberpolice for every forum, be my guest.

Comment: Guys this is not constructive. The question is fairly straightforward and answerable. A lot of people may not find it helpful to future readers, and that's why it might have received downvotes. But there's no point discussing it here. Feel free to delete your comments, unless you feel it adds value to the question at hand.